# Android Studio flutter project does not create launcher icon

Tags: android, flutter

I had an old version of Android Studio and SDK. I uninstalled both and installed latest Android Studio Flamingo and SDK. I created a new template project which runs fine on iOS and Android. On iOS it creates launcher icon but does not do that on Android, on physical device as well as emulator.

In AndroidManifest.xml, I see many tags are underlined but I don't know how to fix them.

Flutter doctor output

```
flutter doctor -v                
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.7 on channel stable at /Users/lk/programs/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2ad6cd72c0 (5 weeks ago), 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
    • Engine revision 1837b5be5f
    • Dart version 2.19.4
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Pixel 2 XL (mobile) • 806KPDT1944522 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • macOS (desktop)     • macos          • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome         • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.49

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

All help greatly appreciated

[image: Underlined tags in AndroidManifest.xml file]

[image: Directory structure for launcher icons]

Comment: I can see that you have defined `android:icon` in your AndroidManifest.xml which basically points to your app or launcher icon.

Comment: if you want to show icon for Android & ios. you just need to paste the launcher icon in Mipmap on android & in ios inside the runner folder can see the asset folder inside it can see the app icon then paste all the ios size app icons there.

Comment: My understanding is that the above steps are only required for custom icons. By default, Flutter icon should be installed on Android and it is not doing that. It used to do that before, but does not do it anymore. The underlined tags in AndroidManifest.xml indicate something is wrong. For example, when I hover over android:icon, it displays "unknown attribute".

Answer (score 0):

Use this package it will help, [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

Its a command-line tool which simplifies the task of updating your Flutter app's launcher icon. Fully flexible, allowing you to choose what platform you wish to update the launcher icon for and if you want, the option to keep your old launcher icon in case you want to revert back sometime in the future.

Comment: This is for installing custom icons. My issue is that even the default Flutter icon is not being installed on Android device/emulator

Comment: I installed all the required images now, but it still does not show the launcher icons. Pls see the original post for my dir structure for the icon Images

Comment: Update: I see the app launcher icon in the App drawer, but Android Studio does not create the icon on the Home Screen.